# AWS ALB listeners - both https and http

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I've got an ALB with a listener on https/443, that forwards the request to the target group that is attached to a Fargate service.

This ALB is open to the Internet, and also part of a special VPC that has some other internal services, with inner domain (xxx.local).

I want to call the alb from inside the VPC, with xxx.local, but I want to allow it to be http/8000 request.

When I add another listener on http/8000 that forwards the request to the same target group - it doesn't work.  If I replace the forward rule to a redirect rule to https/443, it still doesn't work.

any help will be appreciated!

edited: added the image below - both listeners forward to same group

[image]

i've created all the resouces with cloudformation stacks, here's the related part. i've changed it to 2 TGs, still only the 443 works...
here the related code of the stacks:

```
  TargetGroup1:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: TargetGroup1
      Protocol: HTTP
      Port: 8000
      TargetType: ip
      ...
  TargetGroup2:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: TargetGroup2
      Protocol: HTTP
      Port: 8000
      TargetType: ip
      ...

  Listener443:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    DependsOn:
      ...
    Properties:
      Certificates:
        ...
      DefaultActions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'TargetGroup1'
          Type: 'forward'
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref 'TheAlb'
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
      SslPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-2016-08
  Listener8000:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    DependsOn:
      ...
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref 'TargetGroup2'
          Type: 'forward'
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref 'TheAlb'
      Port: 8000
      Protocol: HTTP

  FargateService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn:
      ...
    Properties:
      ...
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: ContainerName
          ContainerPort: ContainerPort
          TargetGroupArn: !Sub
            - "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${tgFullName}"
            - tgFullName: !GetAtt 'TargetGroup1.TargetGroupFullName'

        - ContainerName: ContainerName
          ContainerPort: ContainerPort
          TargetGroupArn: !Sub
            - "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${tgFullName}"
            - tgFullName: !GetAtt 'TargetGroup2.TargetGroupFullName'
```

Comment: Hi, any chance you can provide a screenshot of the listeners? That'll help to see the actual setup easier :)

Comment: @mokugo-devops - just added the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a second target group and edit the 8000 listener to use that target group instead. During the wizard it will only create 1 target group

Comment: Hi, can you confirm that the security group allows port 8000 access? This will need to be public ip of the NAT that fargate uses, not the internal ip

Comment: anyway, i've added the EIP to the  SG (like that: xx.xx.xx.xx/32) and allowed port 8000 inbound from it - but still - it seems not to work (the way i'm checking it is from internal EC2 machine with `wget http://internal.domain`

Comment: nevermind - the problem was on my macine (that i wget from).
thanks!